# Add an item to an array with a key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to convert a line of code to a loop in php:

```
$query[] = [
         'time0'=>$runDate,
         'time1'=> 0,'time2'=> 0, 'time3'=> 0, 'time4'=> 0]; //and so on
```

I have replaced it like this:

```
$timCollection=[];
for($x=1;$x<=48; $x++){
   $temp = 'time'.$x;
   array_push($query,$temp=>0);
}
```

But it produces an array of arrays instead of single array. The result is like this:

```
0: {time1: 0}
   time1: 0
1: {time2: 0}
   time2: 0
2: {time3: 0}
   time3: 0
```

The output I want is like this:

```
0: {time0: "2018-09-24", time1: 0, time2: 0, time3: 0, time4: 0, time5: 0, 
    time6: 0, time7: 0, time8: 0,…}
   time0: "2018-09-24"
   time1: 0
   time2: 0
   time3: 0
   time4: 0
   time5: 0
   time6: 0
   time7: 0
   time8: 0
   .....
```

Anyone has any idea? Maybe I'm just stuck now in one single solution only.

Comment: You can use `$arrayname[indexname] = $value;` instead of `arraypush`

Comment: @Ramesh How can I possibly do it?

Comment: @JonathanGagne With your answer below, seems that you're only looping in the array, what I want is to create that array. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
$timCollection['time0'] = $runDate;
for($x=1;$x<=48; $x++){
    $timCollection['time'.$x] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I think you're only looping in the given array, what I want is to create that array.

Comment: `var_dump` perhaps

Comment: @JonathanGagne As much as I want to accept this solution, it's not what I wanted. Ok. I want to have this result `time0: "2018-09-24"
   time1: 0
   time2: 0
   time3: 0
   time4: 0
   time5: 0
   time6: 0
   time7: 0
   time8: 0` without using this : `$query = [
    'time0'=>date('Y-m-d'),
    'time1'=> 0,
    'time2'=> 0,
    'time3'=> 0,
    'time4'=> 0
];`

Comment: @JonathanGagne Thanks for this man! This is also what I've done as suggested by Ramesh.

Comment: My pleasure! Anytime!

Answer (score 0):

You cant use array_push because it will add a new key at the end. If you want to append new keys in the existing first key then you can try this:

```
    $query[] = [
             'time0'=>$runDate,
             'time1'=> 0,'time2'=> 0, 'time3'=> 0, 'time4'=> 0];
    for($x=1;$x<=48; $x++){
       $temp = 'time'.$x;
       $query[0][$temp]=0;
    }

print_r($query);
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve my goal, I have done it this way as per Ramesh's suggestion:

```
$timCollection=[];
$timCollection['time0']=$runDate;
for($x=1;$x<=48; $x++){
   $temp = 'time'.$x;
   $timCollection[$temp]= 0;
}  
$timCollection= (array)[$timCollection];// just added this line to create one sub array since my 
                         //other data has sub arrays
```

Thanks also Jonathan Gagne for the help.